# How to access reference in reusable workflow

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-reusable-workflows

**Context**

A reusable workflow in public repos may be [called by appending a reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow) which can be a SHA, a release tag, or a branch name, as for example:
`{owner}/{repo}/.github/workflows/{filename}@{ref}`

Githubs [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#overview) states:

> When a reusable workflow is triggered by a caller workflow, the github context is always associated with the caller workflow.

**The problem**

Since the github context is always associated with the caller workflow, the reusable workflow cannot access the reference, for example the tag `v1.0.0`. However, knowing the reference is important when the reusable workflow needs to checkout the repository in order to make use of composite actions.

**Example**

Assume that the caller workflow is being executed from within the `main` branch and calls the ref `v1.0.0.` of a reusable workflow:

```
name: Caller workflow
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  caller:
    uses: owner/public-repo/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@v1.0.0
```

Here is the reusable workflow that uses a composite action:

```
name: reusable workflows
on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  first-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3.1.0
        with:
          repository: owner/public-repo
          ref: ${{ github.ref_name }}

      - name: composite action
        uses: ./actions/my-composite-action
```

In the above code snippet, `${{ github.ref_name }}` is `main` instead of `v1.0.0` because github context is always associated with the caller workflow. Therefore, the composite actions code is based on `main` and not on `v1.0.0`. However, the caller wanted `v1.0.0`.
Hence my question: how is the reusable workflow able to access the reference given by the caller?

Comment: i am having the exact same issue ser - did you find a solution?

Comment: @Cesar I opened an issue but it's not yet replied.
https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/1264